# Unmet peer dependency for sinon package in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sinon

I tried to install `sinon` via npm: `npm install sinon --save-dev`

But I got a unmet peer dependency error:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY sinon@2.3.8
└── sinon-chai@2.8.0 extraneous

npm ERR! peer dep missing: sinon@>=1.4.0 <2, required by sinon-chai@2.8.0
```

I do not understand why sinon should be <2 as I installed the current version, which is 2.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only misunderstood the error message. It's telling you that `sinon-chai` requires `sinon` in the range `>=1.4.0 <2`. Installing version `2.3.8` does not provide a compatible version to `sinon-chai`.

You have two choices: either specifically install a version of `sinon` in the given range; or update `sinon-chai` to version `2.12.0`, which supports a more recent version range:

```
"dependencies": {
    "sinon-chai": "^2.12.0",
    "sinon": "^2.3.8",
    ...
}
```